# Can't access my WP dashboard: fatal error?

Tags: plugins, redirect, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, fatal-error

I can't access my dashboard. It started after making a 301 redirect using a plugin. The redirection won't load nor entry, so I refreshed the page and got this message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   WPSEO_Configuration_Page::set_hooks() in
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-seo\admin\class-admin.php
>   on line 91

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE! Are you using Yoast SEO plugin? I think this function belongs to that plugin.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I actually updated my plugin yesterday and did not even consider that possibility. What can I do to fix it if I can not even access the dashboard? :(

Comment: rename the folder /plugins/wordpress-seo/ and see if you can access the dashboard, if so try to update/reinstall/rollback the plugin

Comment: You can use ftp to disable your plugin. Just navigate to `wp-content/plugins/` and change Yoast's folder name. You will have access to dashboard again.